lxml.etree Elements dropping namespace on copy
I am stitching together XML files using the lxml.etree library and namespaces are being dropped on write.
Input.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<haul>
    <uuid>abc</uuid>
    <port xmlns="hello"
          xmlns:a="hello">
        <v>
            <a:value>0</a:value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
    </port>
</haul>


I tried this code:
test.py

tree = load_tree_from_file('Input.xml')
port = tree.find('{hello}port')
v = port.find('{hello}v')
v2=copy.deepcopy(v)
port.append(v2)

d = os.path.dirname(__file__)
tree.write(os.path.join(d, 'Output.xml'))


I got this output:
Output.xml

<haul>
    <uuid>abc</uuid>
    <port xmlns="hello" xmlns:a="hello">
        <v>
            <a:value>0</a:value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
        <v>
            <value>0</value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
    </port>
</haul>

I expected--and need--the <value> Element to be <a:value> like the first one.

Why not to use XSLT for the task?

I have no idea what XSLT is and also this is a simplified example of how I am manipulating the XML structure.  My actual use case is very complex with many functions and computations, and I tried to distill it down to the simplest example here.  I just want the simplest minimal solution.

When posting code, please ensure that it runs. For example, don't leave out import statements.

The same URL in namespaces should be avoided - confusing not only human, also tools as you can see.

Here is XSLT based solution.
It is using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
One single XSLT template is copying v XML element with all its children twice.
Input XML
<haul>
    <uuid>abc</uuid>
    <port xmlns="hello" xmlns:a="hello">
        <v>
            <a:value>0</a:value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
    </port>
</haul>

XSLT
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="hello">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:v">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<haul>
  <uuid>abc</uuid>
  <port xmlns="hello" xmlns:a="hello">
    <v>
      <a:value>0</a:value>
      <type>int</type>
    </v>
    <v>
      <a:value>0</a:value>
      <type>int</type>
    </v>
  </port>
</haul>

Python
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Process.xslt")
outfile = "Output.xml"

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open(outfile, "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)


Namespace isn't dropped as the specific node has the a namespace be hello which is also identical to the default namespace as specified using xmlns="hello".  This allows the a: prefix for the tag be omitted as both <a:value/> and <value/> are identical representation. Doing something similar if the a namespace was bound to something else will show the kind of output that you were expecting:
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> ixml = b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <haul>
...     <uuid>abc</uuid>
...     <port xmlns="hello"
...           xmlns:a="goodbye">
...         <v>
...             <a:value>0</a:value>
...             <type>int</type>
...         </v>
...     </port>
... </haul>'''
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(ixml)
>>> port = tree.find('{hello}port')
>>> v = port.find('{hello}v')
>>> v2 = copy.deepcopy(v)
>>> port.append(v2)
>>> print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
<haul>
    <uuid>abc</uuid>
    <port xmlns="hello" xmlns:a="goodbye">
        <v>
            <a:value>0</a:value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
    <v>
            <a:value>0</a:value>
            <type>int</type>
        </v>
    </port>
</haul>

Though naturally this example has two separate namespace so it may not be representative of what you are trying to do. In any case the output lxml provided are correct for both cases here, as the version in the question both the default namespace and the a namespace are identical so it may be safely omitted, while the above example in this answer has two separate namespaces so they must be included.  Further examples of how these representations work may be found in this answer.
If the verbose form is desired, using XSLT may be done, which this example shows how it may be done.
